# How can I repair a red 12v train motor from Set# 7730?

Tags: trains, repair, 12v

I have a LEGO 7865 Red 12 volt train motor from a LEGO 7730 train set.  The motor has stopped working as it has been dropped on one of the wheels.

How can I open the motor case to effect a repair?

Comment: Do you want to open the train unit or the motor itself?

Comment: I need to open the red case of the motor itself. I think that one of the gears has been forced out of engagement, maybe the shaft is bent,

Answer (score 1):

According to Bricklink,  Set # 7730 has this motor :

[bb12va Electric, Train Motor 12V Modern Type I with 2 round contact holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb12va&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

For disassembly and repair you can look at this [large post with pictures on Eurobricks](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/113994-12v-train-motorbb12v-disassembly-and-repair/) by Andromeda

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, repairing it will not work, if the shaft is bent, as the wheel would just fall off again.

Comment: Replacing shafts is something routinely done on non - LEGO mechanisms. Why wouldn't it work here, if it's bent?